# What should I do if I have added extra water in rice for braising and you can see the rice is turning into sticky rice?

Tags: rice, water, sticky-rice

While cooking rice with meat, sometimes I faced that extra water has been added to the rice container when kept for braising. What should I do when I see the rice is turning into fluid? Need opinions to be proactive for the future same conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At that point, I'm not sure there's anything you can really do, except maybe take the lid off & attempt to dry it out before it turns entirely to mush.

For next time, the three simplest alternatives would be:

1. Use less liquid [which may not be possible].
2. Add the rice later in the process.

or my personal favourite...

3. Cook the rice separately, in a similar or complementary flavour & combine at the end.

Comment: Rice would take lesser time than meat to cook. so probably cook the meat first about halfway or more, measure the water remaining according to the [rice to water ratio](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/190/proper-ratio-of-water-to-rice) required according to the type of rice and remove any excess.

Comment: I'd really go for option 3. It needs zero skill/judgement/guesswork & can't go wrong, assuming you can actually cook rice ;) Any other method requires you to know how much water the rice will absorb over how long, & how much needs to be left at the end to go with the braise. Does it have sauce/gravy, should it be dry like a biryani?

Comment: Agreed! No wonder people don't like cooking rice :D it's just so complicated.

Comment: Yes, the rice needs to be dry like Beryani in my most cases